# Как создать src изображения в JS?

Tags: javascript

Как в js создать src для изображения? Тег и класс изображения я создал, а каким образом создать src я не понимаю =(

```js
let main = document.querySelector('.main_block');
let child_block = document.querySelector('.child_block');

let xep = document.createElement('img');              
xep.className = 'img_s';
child_block.prepend(xep);
```

```css
body{
display:grid;
place-items:center;     
user-select:none;
}


.main_block{
display:grid;
place-items:center; 
border:1px solid black;
width: 50%;
height:500px;
margin:50px;

}

.img_s{
width:100%;
border:1px solid red;
}

.child_block{

width:50%;
height:50%;     
}
```

```html
<div class = "main_block">

<div class = "child_block">


</div>

</div>
```

Comment: чтобы был src, его надо добавить, не правда ли?

Comment: Ну я не знаю как его добавить через js, знал бы не писал сюда.

Comment: точно так же, как ты добавил класс в тег

Comment: xep.src ? Можно полный пример синтаксиса?

Comment: ты только что его написал в своём комментарии

Comment: но я не уверен в этом. как называется этот метод, можно пожалуйста ссылку на описание

Comment: это не метод, это свойство объекта. свойство для тега в js - атрибут в отображении

Comment: А где можно прочитать про добавления src к изображению через JS?

Comment: ........В книге?

Comment: Ну или на худой конец в доках..........любыыыых........https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135619/discussion-between-black-viper-and--).

Comment: Ну че вы минус поставили =( Я же за вас голосовал на выборах

Comment: Какой минус? Какие выборы? Что за бред.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так же, как вы добавили класс только что созданному изображению можно добавить и src-свойство. Очень многие свойства объектов на странице можно так изменить.

Пробуйте гуглить, как изменить тот или иной атрибут элемента. Или попробуйте вывести нужный элемент в консоль через `console.dir()`, там будут показаны все свойства объекта, их сможете менять. Например, попробуйте добавить в ваш код     `console.dir(xep)` и посмотреть, что выведет.

```js
let main = document.querySelector('.main_block');
let child_block = document.querySelector('.child_block');

let xep = document.createElement('img');              
xep.className = 'img_s';
xep.src = 'https://pets.mail.ru/pre_rect840x0_resize/pic/wysiwyg/2019/05/17/IMG_7005.jpg';
child_block.prepend(xep);
```

```css
body{
display:grid;
place-items:center;     
user-select:none;
}


.main_block{
display:grid;
place-items:center; 
border:1px solid black;
width: 50%;
height:500px;
margin:50px;

}

.img_s{
width:100%;
border:1px solid red;
}

.child_block{

width:50%;
height:50%;     
}
```

```html
<div class = "main_block">

<div class = "child_block">


</div>

</div>
```

Comment: А я нашел еще один способ: xep.setAttribute('src', '1.jpg); чем он лучше xep.src?

Comment: Почти всегда это одно и то же и, наверное, часто нет особой разницы, какой использовать. `.src=` обращается к свойству объекта в javascript. А `get/set/has/removeAttribute` работает напрямую с элементом на странице. Например, иногда свойства объекта (первый способ) может отличаться от атрибутов (второй способ), так как объект создается после обработки браузером.

Comment: Благодарю, вы мне очень помогли =)